# How do I get a MakeMaker target for code coverage?

Tags: perl, code-coverage, makemaker

In my ExtUtils::MakeMaker based project, I want to generate a code coverage report from my tests. I use Devel::Cover for that, but I have to run it manually:

```
HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover make test && cover
```

That's too much to type (and remember), so I'd like to run something like `make cover` instead. [ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SMPETERS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-Coverage-0.05/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/Coverage.pm) seems to do that, but I cannot install it.

```
~/pl$ sudo cpan install ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/Users/rwenner/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Thu, 08 Oct 2020 22:56:18 GMT
>(error): Could not expand [ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage]. Check the module name.
>(info): I can suggest names if you install one of Text::Levenshtein::XS, Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::XS, Text::Levenshtein, and Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::PP
>(info): and you provide the -x option on invocation.
>(error): Skipping ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
```

Why is that and how can I install that module? I can install other modules with `cpan` just fine, so I don't think it's a network issue.

Or is ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage outdated (looks like the last update is from 2005)? What should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add a postamble](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Overriding-MakeMaker-Methods) to your `Makefile.PL`:

```
# Makefile.PL
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
WriteMakefile(...);

# specify additional testing targets
package MY;
sub MY::postamble {
    return q~
cover :: pure_all
    HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover make test && cover

    ~;
}
```

This will add a target that will execute your desired command when you run `make cover`.